# Errors reported when importing Android source code into ADT (Eclipse)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt, android-source

I downloaded source code and built Android (version 4.3) without errors (it works fine if I run it in emulator). 
Now I'm following this tutorial https://source.android.com/source/using-eclipse.html to import Android Project into eclipse workspace. After creating project from existing code, when workspace rebuild, eclipse throws 5131 errors and 12029 warnings.

As far as I see, all errors are of same origin "Something cannot be resolved..."

For example in packages/apps/Calendar/src in package com.android.calendar there is EventInfoFragment class with following imports:

```
import static android.provider.CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_ALL_DAY;
import static android.provider.CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME;
import static android.provider.CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME;
import static com.android.calendar.CalendarController.EVENT_EDIT_ON_LAUNCH;

import android.animation.Animator;
import android.animation.AnimatorListenerAdapter;
import android.animation.ObjectAnimator;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.ContentProviderOperation;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.ContentUris;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager.NameNotFoundException;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.CalendarContract;
import android.provider.CalendarContract.Attendees;
import android.provider.CalendarContract.Calendars;
import android.provider.CalendarContract.Colors;
import android.provider.CalendarContract.Events;
import android.provider.CalendarContract.Reminders;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.Intents;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.QuickContact;
import android.text.Spannable;
import android.text.SpannableStringBuilder;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.text.format.Time;
import android.text.method.LinkMovementMethod;
import android.text.method.MovementMethod;
import android.text.style.ForegroundColorSpan;
import android.text.util.Rfc822Token;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.SparseIntArray;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityEvent;
import android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityManager;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.calendar.CalendarController.EventInfo;
import com.android.calendar.CalendarController.EventType;
import com.android.calendar.CalendarEventModel.Attendee;
import com.android.calendar.CalendarEventModel.ReminderEntry;
import com.android.calendar.alerts.QuickResponseActivity;
import com.android.calendar.event.AttendeesView;
import com.android.calendar.event.EditEventActivity;
import com.android.calendar.event.EditEventHelper;
import com.android.calendar.event.EventColorPickerDialog;
import com.android.calendar.event.EventViewUtils;
import com.android.calendarcommon2.DateException;
import com.android.calendarcommon2.Duration;
import com.android.calendarcommon2.EventRecurrence;
import com.android.colorpicker.ColorPickerSwatch.OnColorSelectedListener;
import com.android.colorpicker.HsvColorComparator;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
```

These imports cannot be resolved:

```
import com.android.colorpicker.ColorPickerSwatch.OnColorSelectedListener;
import com.android.colorpicker.HsvColorComparator;
```

My eclipse is from ADT.

I think that project is missing some libs/jars but I'm stuck here. If anyone have an idea, I will be most thankfull.

Comment: by `something`, do you mean **R**?

Answer (score 1):

There are no such imports: `com.android.colorpicker.*` in the official SDK.
A little search brought me up with this library: [Android Colorpicker](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/opt/colorpicker/+/android-4.4_r0.7) that uses the packagename `com.android.colorpicker`. So try importing this library and add it to your imported project.

Answer (score 0):

Delete bin folder in your project then clean your project.
if your problem is not solved, probably problem is SDK files.
also you can try this way:
1 - create a new project
2 - delete fragment_main in res/layout
3 - delete all generated code in main_activity class except:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

Note: MainActivity must extend Activity instead of ActionBarActivity